# CVXOPT in Python fails to solve simple quadratic programming problen

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, cvxopt, quadratic-programming

I'm using CVXOPT in Python to try to solve a fairly simple quadratic programming problem. I'm finding that it works perfectly for some values of my parameters, but fails for others.

Shown below is a very simple example of `cvxopt.solvers.qp()` failing for one of three examples.

You can see that all the examples are very similar in nature. Could anyone tell me why CVXOPT is failing to solve the middle of the three?

Many thanks

```
import numpy as np
from cvxopt.solvers import qp
from cvxopt import matrix

print '-'*70
print 'Case 1:'
P = np.array([[ 0.0084,  0.003 ],
              [ 0.003,   0.0017]])
q = np.array([[-0.36],
              [-0.02]])
G = np.array([[ 1.,  0.],
              [ 0.,  1.]])
h = np.array([[ 500.],
              [ 500.]])

results = qp(
    matrix(P),
    matrix(q),
    matrix(G),
    matrix(h),
)
print results # Works fine, {'status': 'optimal'}
print results['x']
print 'Works fine'


print '-'*70
print 'Case 2:'
P = np.array([[ 0.0042 ,  0.0015 ],
              [ 0.0015 ,  0.00085]])
q = np.array([[-0.48],
              [-0.06]])
G = np.array([[ 1.,  0.],
              [ 0.,  1.]])
h = np.array([[ 500.],
              [ 500.]])

results = qp(
    matrix(P),
    matrix(q),
    matrix(G),
    matrix(h),
)
print results # Fails, reaches max_iter, {'status': 'unknown'}
print '***Fails***'



print '-'*70
print 'Case 3:'
P = np.array([[ 0.0021  ,  0.00075 ],
              [ 0.00075 ,  0.000425]])
q = np.array([[-0.54],
              [-0.08]])
G = np.array([[ 1.,  0.],
              [ 0.,  1.]])
h = np.array([[ 500.],
              [ 500.]])

results = qp(
    matrix(P),
    matrix(q),
    matrix(G),
    matrix(h),
)
print results # Works fine, {'status': 'optimal'}
print results['x']
print 'Works fine'
```

Comment: I can't tell you why it fails, but keep in mind that QP's are not trivial and no solver is perfect. There will always be troublesome instances although it's a bit annoying if it happen's in such a small problem like that. It sure is somehow diverging here as increasing the number of iterations does not help. The commercial solver MOSEK has no problem at all.

Answer (score 3):

Apologies, I don't have enough reputation to edit my question.

Someone on a Google group pointed out the answer. It is that my problem is not well scaled. It is best for the elements of `h` to be close to 1.

So dividing both `G` and `h` through by 500 allowed the optimiser to work perfectly and give a correct answer in all cases above.

It's strange, I can't find any mention of this scaling stuff in the CVXOPT docs.

Anyway, I hope this question and answer proves useful to someone.

```
print '-'*70
print 'Case 2:'
P = np.array([[ 0.0042 ,  0.0015 ],
              [ 0.0015 ,  0.00085]])
q = np.array([[-0.48],
              [-0.06]])
G = np.array([[ 1.,  0.],
              [ 0.,  1.]])
h = np.array([[ 500.],
              [ 500.]])

# Divide by 500 to get scaling correct
G /= 500
h /= 500

results = qp(
    matrix(P),
    matrix(q),
    matrix(G),
    matrix(h),
)
print results # Works fine, {'status': 'optimal'}
print 'Works fine'
```